# Power query's Data from PDF not always reliable, possible to Iterate over url links to download PDFs and convert full text?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Kind of a 2 part question depending on whether or not the first is possible to change. I suspect it is not so please skip to problem 2:

**Problem 1:**

So with Power Query data sources, you can get data from both PDF files as well as PDFs from URLs. Therefore, it is possible to generate a function that can iterate over either a file or a list of URLs to perform data transformations to each. In my case I am interested in separating the text into its constituent sentences where paragraphs of text are present. The latter has been achieved. However, there is a particular issue when extracting data from certain PDFs.

For example : https://hpvchemicals.oecd.org/ui/handler.axd?id=621c4f55-ef3c-4b99-bb98-e6aaf3f436dd

When pulled into PQ; M Code:

```
let
    Source = Pdf.Tables(Web.Contents("https://hpvchemicals.oecd.org/ui/handler.axd?id=621c4f55-ef3c-4b99-bb98-e6aaf3f436dd"), [Implementation="1.3"]),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Kind] = "Page")),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Data"}),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Data", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18"})
in
    #"Expanded Data"
```

Although this detects the text, it appears to merge words as shown here:

[image]

So my first question is, does anyone know why this happens and if so if anything can be done to prevent this?

I have checked the PDF for hidden characters etc, but these do not appear to be present. Next I have checked to see if using some online text extraction tool delivers the same result.

Simply enter the same URL here https://www.pdf2go.com/pdf-to-text and downloading the text file produced:

[image]

Produces a much more reliable result. So it makes sense if the first problem cannot be resolved to download all the PDFs from URL links in bulk and from this, convert these to text files and finally connect these to power query. I suspect this, although roundabout way, will produce much more reliable results.

**Problem2/Question:**
How can I write a script that iterates over a list of Urls, Download each of the PDF files, and converts these to a text file?

The plan is to have a separate excel based tool to achieve this and then throw the raw text data into PQ for the extraction.

I will be posting progress made here, but if anyone can offer any info to either the first question or how to achieve this second question in VBA that would be great.

**Progress:** TBC

Comment: You can download each file, open it in Word (which does a pretty good job with the text) and extract the text from the Word doc.

Comment: I have hundreds of URLs to go through you see

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you do it manually - it can all be automated using VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Word to convert the PDF's.

For example:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim oWd As Object, oDoc As Object, c As Range
    
    Set oWd = CreateObject("word.application")
    oWd.Visible = True
    
    For Each c In Range("A1:A5").Cells
        With oWd.Documents.Open(c.Value)
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = .Range.Text
            'or write to a file...
            .Close
        End With
    Next c
    
    oWd.Quit
    
End Sub
```

Comment: To be honest, there is  a reliable vba script that converts PDF to word/text doc online. I am exploring looping through a series of URLs, downloading the PDF and immediately converting them. Useful to know though

Comment: Also I need the actual text file to be generated to throw this into my PQ function

Comment: So write the text to a file? If you're not sure how to do that there are plenty of examples to be found here on SO, or via Google. You will need to do *some* work here...

Comment: I agree there are a lot of examples online, I will be shortly posting what I have done.

Comment: For some reason with your updated version I get a Type mismatch error. First version appeared to be okay

Comment: Error on which line?

Comment: Works for me as-posted.

Comment: Oh I see what you are doing here, I was unnecessarily adding steps, you actually just pull the text directly into exel. this works as a solution

Answer (score 1):

### **Problem 1:**

The function to convert a pdf is named PDF.Tables.

```
Returns any tables found in pdf.
```

The text is garbled because it is struggling to find any tables although it might be worth feeding this back to MS.

I would abandon this route as PQ is powerful but limited in these circumstances.

### **Problem 2:**

Use Power Automate Desktop. Here is a good tutorial and it should allow you to do all the web scraping and conversion. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgBZiBIgh3w

Comment: Yes, I thought so, though as per the M code, I have filtered out searching Tables. Very strange how PQ interprets Text in PDFs. Power Automate is not a bad idea, though in my limited experience, it seems to be predominately RPA. I prefer the rapid nature of VBA, can also work in the background when running the macro.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple case you can run the one line in a batch so here I simply ask for URL to console, but that was saved as output.txt so can be any variable name for input to say excel. curl is native to windows but for pdftotext get it from github. https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows

[image]

so simply shell as one or more variable lines in a vb loop

`curl -o temp.pdf https://hpvchemicals.oecd.org/ui/handler.axd?id=621c4f55-ef3c-4b99-bb98-e6aaf3f436dd && pdftotext -layout temp.pdf output.txt && type output.txt`

Note do not worry if console text shows some poor UTF handling (thats a chcp issue) the txt file should be ok but you can use `-enc UTF-8` as an extra option. (Also `-nopgbrk` if desired)

Answer (score 0):

For Each URL in Range:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim fileStream As TextStream
    
    Dim oWd As Object, oDoc As Object, c As Range
    
    Set oWd = CreateObject("word.application")
    
    n = 1
    
    For Each c In Range("A1:A2").Cells
    
    filePath = "C:\temp\" & n & "MyTestFile.txt"
    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath)
    
    Debug.Print c.Value
        
        With oWd.Documents.Open(c.Value)

            Debug.Print .Range.Text
            'write to a file...
            fileStream.WriteLine .Range.Text
            fileStream.Close
            
        End With
        
        n = n + 1
        
    Next c
    
    oWd.Quit
    
End Sub
```